# Stored procedure with input and output SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a stored procedure that takes a name/or number and returns a specific value for that name/number

So in this code, I am trying to write a stored procedure taht takes a company name or the cvr number and return the degree of compliance for that company

```
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS DRCS;
    CREATE DATABASE DRCS;
    USE DRCS; 

    CREATE TABLE Companies ( 
            ID INT not null,
            Name varchar(255), 
            primary key (ID) 
    ); 

    CREATE TABLE CVR (
            ID INT not null,
            CVR_Number INT 
    ); 

    CREATE TABLE Compliance (
            ID INT not null,
            Complaince_level varchar(255)
    ); 

    CREATE TABLE GDPR (
            ID INT not null,
            GDPR_steps varchar(255) 
    ); 

                INSERT INTO Companies VALUES 
                (1, 'TDC'),
                (2, 'MAERSK'),
                (3, 'LEGO'), 
                (4, 'SAS'),
                (5, 'Carlsberg');

                INSERT INTO CVR VALUES 
                (11, '14773908'),
                (12, '32345794'),
                (13, '47458714'),
                (14, '56994912'),
                (15, '61056416');

                INSERT INTO Compliance VALUES 
                (21, '10%'),
                (22, '20%'),
                (23, '40%'),
                (24, '60%'),
                (25, '80%');

                INSERT INTO GDPR VALUES 
                (31, '1. Awareness'),
                (32, '2. Information you hold'),
                (33, '3. Communication privacy information'),
                (34, '4. Individuals rights'),
                (35, '5. Subject access requests'); 

#HERE MY PROBLEM STARTS                

    DELIMITER $$
        CREATE PROCEDURE DoC() 
        BEGIN 
        SELECT * FROM Companies , CVR, Compliance, GDPR; 

        END $$
    DELIMITER ;


    CALL DoC;
```

Comment: Stored procedures don't "return" values.  Perhaps you want a function.

Comment: Care to elaborate on what the problem ***is***?  Maybe error messages?

Comment: Well, stored procedure is just a stored function so, yes it is a function i trying to code.

Comment: @MatBailie, it is not the errors that is the problem is how I will proceed. I just asking if you amazing people have any ideas to my problem.

Comment: "Well, stored procedure is just a stored function .." No thats not true MySQL documentation makes clear distinction between a stored procedure and a stored function..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Yes you are right, I just formulatet my statement wrong. However my task is to write a stored procedure that returns a spesific value.

Comment: Why a stored procedure? A simple select query also would do the trick assuming you fixed/added the relations between the tables.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, haha yes! I agree so much and have tried to convert our task to just that. However, it is not me that decided how we must do this, it's my supervisors. It's a must that we do a stored procedure, unfortunately.. Its, therefore, I really need help, because I dont understand how.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Stored functions are similar to procedures, except that a function returns a value to the environment in which it is called.

Comment: I suspect you need to pass a parameter to the s, test if it is numeric or string and use an if statement to decide to run one of 2 queries.

Comment: @P.Salmon what do you mean with s

Comment: Sorry sp(stored procedure)

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between the four tables!
Create rows with common id like id = 1,2,3,4 for all tables and then do a join and then try to list the fields you want to view.

INSERT INTO Companies VALUES 
                (1, 'TDC'),
                (2, 'MAERSK'),
                (3, 'LEGO'), 
                (4, 'SAS'),
                (5, 'Carlsberg');

```
            INSERT INTO CVR VALUES 
            (1, '14773908'),
            (2, '32345794'),
            (3, '47458714'),
            (4, '56994912'),
            (5, '61056416');

            INSERT INTO Compliance VALUES 
            (1, '10%'),
            (2, '20%'),
            (3, '40%'),
            (4, '60%'),
            (5, '80%');

            INSERT INTO GDPR VALUES 
            (1, '1. Awareness'),
            (2, '2. Information you hold'),
            (3, '3. Communication privacy information'),
            (4, '4. Individuals rights'),
            (5, '5. Subject access requests');
```

select c.id,v.cvr_Number from Companies c, cvr v where c.id = v.id

Similarly add more tables by joining with id. You don't need a procedure to this and a procedure is not designed for this.

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing now. However that will just create a table whitch shows all the relationships, not solve my function problem.

Comment: Write a fn that will return one value, based on your input. Select field from table a, table b where a.id = b.id;

Answer (score 0):

You can make with union query for all table. But all select query of clomum count should be same.

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE DoC() 
  SELECT A.id,A.name FROM
   ( SELECT id as id , name as name FROM Companies 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id as id , name as name FROM CVR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id as id , name as name FROM Compliance
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id as id , name as name FROM  GDPR) as A

  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```